# GMS is an open source technologies based platform. (Is it correct)

Tags: punctuation, commas

Got confused about this line.

```
GMS is an open source technologies based platform.
```

Is this sentence is correct?

> **Friend A** *(Arguing)*: GMS is an, open source technologies based
>      platform.(is right so no prob with sentence)
>
> **Friend B** *(Arguing)*: GMS is ,an open source technologies based
>   platform.(is wrong so sentence is wrong.)

Who is right?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both friends are wrong. You don't use a comma to divide a copular construction like "X is Y".

Comment: `GMS is an open source technologies based platform` is it gramatically correct?

Comment: It is most definetley correct @SubinCPoonamgode

Comment: Well, it's open-source, but grammatically it is correct.

Comment: I meant to say that "GMS is an open source technologies based platform" is very much grammatically correct, in answer to your question in the comments section

Comment: There should be no comma in that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is grammatical in English to chain and nest modifiers like this:

**GMS is an {  {open-source technologies}-based } platform**

chaining and nesting are not as clear as subordination:

```
GMS is a platform which is based on open-source technologies.

GMS is a platform based on open-source technologies.
```

or this:

```
The GMS platform is based on open-source technologies.
```